# Firestore query a lot of documents

Tags: firebase, kotlin, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore database with a lot of data in it.

In my application I have to get a lot of documents from it at once.
I know the exact keys of them. It is maximum 500-600 documents at a time, and an average of 300 of them, with only 3 fields in each.
Is the best way to get them one-by-one in a new thread and request for each? This needs a lot of parallel connections..

This is what I do now, but it is a bit slow (several secs), I am looking for a better solution now. I have no opportunity to merge these into bigger documents, as I may need very different set of them...

I am running these on a ktor backend server.

Comment: Is there a field that you can add to these documents which would allow you to run a query?  This would be the fastest method.  In the node.js SDK there is a .getAll method.  I'm struggling to find anything like this for Android in the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore)

Comment: I am using the admin API, as it is a ktor backend server, I don't see there anything like that.

Comment: In that case, I can post an answer for you in a few minutes. I'm not sure how well it will work with 500 documents. You may be better using pagination, in your app and get smaller blocks, each time.

Comment: Pagination is not possible in my special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Admin SDK, you can easily retrieve multiple documents at the same time, using [getAll](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/latest/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/Firestore.html) (linked to the documentation).  Simply call `firestore.getAll` and pass a list of document references.

Comment: Okay, now I see, that there is a getAll method, which would maybe help me. I will test and benchmark it soon.

However, I am still using kotlin ktor backend, with java admin sdk, so the link is not correct.

I found the get all method, I can call it like this:
val db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore()
db.getall(....){...}

Comment: I must admit that I wasn't aware of a Java Admin SDK. I assumed that the Admin SDK only supports Node. I'll take a look through the Java SDK and update my answer

Comment: Please update it, and then I can accept it as a good answer.

My API is now abut 2 times as fast as it was:

Normal coorutine based multiple parallel requests: ~2500 microsec

Using get all method: **~1400 microsec**

This is excellent for my usage.

Comment: It took a fair bit of searching, but I found the reference and I've updated the answer.  I'm glad to hear that it resolved your issue.